# Specify the memory start address for a process

Tags: c++

I wish to know if it is possible to load the process at a user (pre)specified address?

Thanks,
Ashutosh

Comment: You need to consult the documentation for your specific tool-chain, or at least specify it for people here.  The C++ Standard itself does not require any, or document any potential, facility for this.

Answer (score 3):

The base address is specified in the PE file. If you mean for an EXE that you're compiling in MSVC, then you can set the base address in the linker settings. If you've got an arbitrary EXE or DLL, you could alter the base address by hand, with a good PE resource.  You should also turn off ASLR - it's also a project setting and in the PE file.

Most EXE files load at their preferred base address as when you start a process with one, it's the only thing in the address space, and it's not unheard of for exe files to skip the relocation table. DLLs however sometimes have to be re-based. It's not a good idea at all to depend on loading at a specific base address.

Comment: And don't forget to disable the ASLR.